# Pages 4.3 crashes on iMac Late 2013 Mavericks

Tags: macos, crash, pages, iwork

Pages 4.3 (latest update for iWork '09 afaik) constantly crashes (closes and shows "unexpectly quit" crash report) on a new iMac 27" (Late 2013) running 10.9 (.2) Mavericks
The crashes seem to be comepletely intermittent. Sometimes when writing, pasting text, dragging images.

Here are some crash reports:
http://pastebin.com/xTszDwNG (latest one, this one was when a image was dragged into pages)
http://pastebin.com/k9NsMFpt
http://pastebin.com/kYxh71np
http://pastebin.com/TUMQctDL

The latest one:
http://pastebin.com/g142aypG

This one happened after I completely reinstalled the machine (formatted the drive, installed mavericks over restore partition, created a new user, installed iwork from disc and installed 4.3 update and then dragged over my personal documents via a usb drive)

**EDIT**
I ended up updating to the new versions of pages since I couldn't get the bug to be fixed.

Comment: Is this happening with just 1 file or all old files? Also am I to understand that this wasn't an issue until after you reinstalled? Or did you have the issue and then reinstall?

Comment: this happens on all kinds of files
newly created empty ones, newly created from a template or even ones that other people sent

Comment: To check if it was just a general Mavericks based bug, I opened Pages 4.3 (1048) and tried some of your actions. My version (on 10.9.2) does not crash.

Comment: The crashes are very intermittent, sometimes i can work for a few hours without pages crashing. As an additional info: it can't be a hardware issue. The mac has been cloned onto a same-model iMac (except with a fusion drive). That one had the same issues.

Comment: Ok, I only tested for like 10 minutes, I'll leave it running for a while.

Comment: Leaving Pages4.3 open for hours and interacting with it from time to time did not cause it to crash on my machine. (Just trying to make sure there isn't a generic Pages>Mavericks interaction causing a crash) It can still be a software issue, e.g. some setting that is causing it.

Comment: Since the imac was freshly reinstalled with only mail, pages and office in the use - everything is as default as it can possibly be

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off topic, but with Mavericks installed, you can update to Pages 5.1 for no charge and maybe your problem will not occur.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2056159/what-you-need-to-know-about-apples-free-apps-policy.html

Comment: Think very carefully before upgrading to 5.1 Pages. It is very greatly disliked by 9 out of 10 users (Wikipedia). It removes many useful features.